# Sharp Architecture issue with EntityWithTypedId

Tags: fluent-nhibernate, sharp-architecture

I wish to use Guid comb for my identity. I've added the EntityWithTypedId interface to my class which cause my table not to persist. ie using nh prof i can see the SaveOrUpdate method is not called. If i just use the Entity interface i can see it in the profiler.

```
public class Application : EntityWithTypedId<Guid>
{
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual string CreatedByUserName { get; set; }
    public virtual string ModifiedByUserName { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime Created { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime Modified { get; set; }
}


public class ApplicationQuery : NHibernateQuery, IApplicationQuery
{

    public void Update(Application application)
    {
        Session.SaveOrUpdate(application);

    }
}

public class ApplicationMap : IAutoMappingOverride<Application>
{
    public void Override(AutoMapping<Application> mapping)
    {
        mapping.Table("Application");
        mapping.Id(x => x.Id, "Id").GeneratedBy.GuidComb();
    }
}
```

Controller

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ActionName("Edit")]
    public ActionResult EditPost(Application application)
    {
        var updateApplication = new Application();
        updateApplication.Created = DateTime.Now;
        updateApplication.Modified = DateTime.Now;
        _applicationQuery.Update(updateApplication);
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by updating my mapping to the following.

```
 public void Override(AutoMapping<Application> mapping)
        {
            mapping.Table("Application");
            mapping.Id(x => x.Id, "Id").GeneratedBy.GuidComb().UnsavedValue(Guid.Empty);

        }
```

See here for more info.

http://s274.codeinspot.com/q/1486941